# Dynamically creating a where clause for a list of items based on a user-provided search string and column name

Tags: c#, linq, blazor

The following code is my attempt but I am getting the following errors:

> 1.) BinaryExpression Expression.Or(Expression, Expression) has the wrong return type

> 2.) Error (active)    CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression>' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression'      c:\Users\HNchapajr\source\repos\copy-working\bge\bge\Components\Test\Filter.razor   118
>
> 3.) Error (active)    CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression' to 'bool'     c:\Users\HNchapajr\source\repos\copy-working\bge\bge\Components\Test\Filter.razor   118

Code where the issue is at:

- `var orExpression = expressions.Aggregate(Expression.Or);`
- Line 118: `var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TValue, bool>>(expressions, parameter);`

The code below:

```
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Lists
@using System.Linq.Expressions;
@using System.Collections;

@typeparam TValue

<h3>Filter</h3>

@if(IsReady)
{
    <SfListView DataSource="@collections" ShowCheckBox="true">
        <ListViewFieldSettings TValue="DataModel" Text="Text" IsChecked="IsChecked"></ListViewFieldSettings>
    </SfListView>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="OnFilter">Filter!</button>
}


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<TValue> DataSource { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public List<TValue> DataSourceChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter] 
    public string Column { get; set; } = string.Empty;


    List<DataModel> collections { get; set; } = new List<DataModel>();

    bool IsReady = false;

    public class DataModel

    {
        public string? Text { get; set; }
        public string? Id { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        IsReady = false;
        ParseNested();
    }

    private void ParseNested()
    {
        if (DataSource != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Column))
        {
            var splitColumn = Column.Split(".");
            if (splitColumn.Length >= 2)
            {
                collections = DataSource.SelectMany(p =>
                {
                    var prop = p.GetType().GetProperty(splitColumn[0]);
                    if (prop != null && prop.GetValue(p) is ICollection col)
                        return col.Cast<object>().Select(cc =>
                        {
                            var nestedProp = cc.GetType().GetProperty(splitColumn[1]);
                            var response = nestedProp != null ? nestedProp.GetValue(cc)?.ToString() : null;
                            return new DataModel
                                {
                                    Text = response
                                };
                        });
                    else
                        return new List<DataModel>();
                }).Where(nc => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(nc.Text))
                .GroupBy(nc => nc.Text)
                .Select(g => g.First())
                .ToList();

                IsReady = true;
            }
        }

    }

    private void OnFilter()
    {


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Column))
        {
            var splitColumn = Column.Split(".");

            if (splitColumn.Length >= 2)
            {
                //var checkedItems = collections.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.Text).ToList();

                //var query = DataSource.AsQueryable();

                //var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TValue), "x");
                //var memberExpression = Column.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.PropertyOrField);

                //var containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
                
                //var expressions = checkedItems.Select(searchString => Expression.Call(memberExpression, containsMethod, Expression.Constant(searchString)));

                ////var orExpression = expressions.Aggregate((left, right) => Expression.OrElse(left, right));

                //var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TValue, bool>>(expressions, parameter);


                //var filterList = query.Where(lambda).ToList();
                var checkedItems = collections.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.Text).ToList();

                var query = DataSource.AsQueryable();

                var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TValue), "x");
                var memberExpression = Column.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.PropertyOrField);

                var containsMethod = typeof(List<string>).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
                var expressions = checkedItems.Select(searchString => Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(checkedItems), containsMethod, Expression.Constant(searchString)));
                var orExpression = expressions.Aggregate(Expression.Or);
                var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TValue, bool>>(expressions, parameter);
                
                var filterList = query.Where(lambda);
                Console.WriteLine(filterList);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Background:**

I have the following class. We are interested on searching the ICollection.

```
public partial class Company{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    public bool Show { get; set; }

    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CompanyCompanyCategory> CompanyCompanyCategory { get; set; } = new List<CompanyCompanyCategory>();
}
```

Here is the CompanyCompnayCategory class for reference:

```
public partial class CompanyCompanyCategory
{
    public int CompanyFk { get; set; }

    public int CompanyCategoryFk { get; set; }

    public virtual CompanyCategory CompanyCategoryFkNavigation { get; set; }

    public virtual Company CompanyFkNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

The razor component code below has a Parameter for DataSource and Column.

Example input for Column would be the following:

`"CompanyCompanyCategory.CompanyFk"`

This above example of a column we want to filter the ids of company which is the variable CompanyFk.

Furthermore, the List we want to filter based on the check boxes withing the ListView.
Once the user selects the SfListView we want to filter the DataSource by using where clause the String Column that contains the property of the collection.

I am open for suggestions and modifications.
The example provided using Company and CompanyCategory is just an example.

We want this to be truly dynamic since we don't know if object we going to pass into the component.

The following code is what I try it starts in the onFilter function:

```
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Lists
@using System.Linq.Expressions;
@using System.Collections;

@typeparam TValue

<h3>Filter</h3>

@if(IsReady)
{
    <SfListView DataSource="@collections" ShowCheckBox="true">
        <ListViewFieldSettings TValue="DataModel" Text="Text" IsChecked="IsChecked"></ListViewFieldSettings>
    </SfListView>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="OnFilter">Filter!</button>
}


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<TValue> DataSource { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public List<TValue> DataSourceChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter] 
    public string Column { get; set; } = string.Empty;


    List<DataModel> collections { get; set; } = new List<DataModel>();

    bool IsReady = false;

    public class DataModel

    {
        public string? Text { get; set; }
        public string? Id { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        IsReady = false;
        ParseNested();
    }

    private void ParseNested()
    {
        if (DataSource != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Column))
        {
            var splitColumn = Column.Split(".");
            if (splitColumn.Length >= 2)
            {
                collections = DataSource.SelectMany(p =>
                {
                    var prop = p.GetType().GetProperty(splitColumn[0]);
                    if (prop != null && prop.GetValue(p) is ICollection col)
                        return col.Cast<object>().Select(cc =>
                        {
                            var nestedProp = cc.GetType().GetProperty(splitColumn[1]);
                            var response = nestedProp != null ? nestedProp.GetValue(cc)?.ToString() : null;
                            return new DataModel
                                {
                                    Text = response
                                };
                        });
                    else
                        return new List<DataModel>();
                }).Where(nc => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(nc.Text))
                .GroupBy(nc => nc.Text)
                .Select(g => g.First())
                .ToList();

                IsReady = true;
            }
        }

    }

    private void OnFilter()
    {


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Column))
        {
            var splitColumn = Column.Split(".");

            if (splitColumn.Length >= 2)
            {
                //var checkedItems = collections.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.Text).ToList();

                //var query = DataSource.AsQueryable();

                //var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TValue), "x");
                //var memberExpression = Column.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.PropertyOrField);

                //var containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
                
                //var expressions = checkedItems.Select(searchString => Expression.Call(memberExpression, containsMethod, Expression.Constant(searchString)));

                ////var orExpression = expressions.Aggregate((left, right) => Expression.OrElse(left, right));

                //var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TValue, bool>>(expressions, parameter);


                //var filterList = query.Where(lambda).ToList();
                var checkedItems = collections.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.Text).ToList();

                var query = DataSource.AsQueryable();

                var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TValue), "x");
                var memberExpression = Column.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.PropertyOrField);

                var containsMethod = typeof(List<string>).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
                var expressions = checkedItems.Select(searchString => Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(checkedItems), containsMethod, Expression.Constant(searchString)));
                var orExpression = expressions.Aggregate(Expression.Or);
                var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TValue, bool>>(expressions, parameter);


                var filterList = query.Where(lambda);
                //Console.WriteLine(filterList);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "We want this to be truly dynamic since we don't know if object we going to pass into the component."  Writing dynamic filtering where you are using generics to define the source and the target is a **VERY BIG** ask.  Take a look at DynamicLinq - https://dynamic-linq.net/.    Depending on your environment, there are many security and performance issues that need to be considered.

Comment: Try `expressions.Cast<Expression>().Aggregate(Expression.OrElse)`. Change the lambda definition to use `orExpression` as the body, not `expressions`.